# How to create only a week calendar with previous and next week buttons

Tags: asp.net

I am really stucked at this.what i want is that there should be 6 table cells in which i should have days with date. like 
Monday 4/3/2013 Tuesday 5/3/2013 and so on till saturday
.i have two more buttons,previous week and next week button.. it should automatically show next week when i click the next week button and should show the previous week whenever i press the previous button..
also the i need to take the value of days/month and year so that i can use them in where clause in my sql query..pls its urgent can anyone help me with this...

im providing a link you can see what exactly i want by visiting this link

[www.test.ginormous.in/dinesmart/Filestore/Food/Capture.png](http://www.test.ginormous.in/dinesmart/Filestore/Food/Capture.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am just giving you the outline as posting the whole code is not possible.

1. create an asp:panel in your aspx page
2. try generating the table structure dynamically inside that panel by writing myPanel.innerhtml = "(your html structure generated in a string)"
3. use **theDate.AddDays(7 - (int)theDate.DayOfWeek)** to get the date for this weeks sunday.(where theDay is the current date or the date given by you and change 7 to 6 if you want it for monday as this returns date for sunday etc..)
4. on previous and next click you can add or subtract 7 days from the first day of the weel that is generated above.

hope this helps you.

Comment: create DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;  theDate = theDate.AddDays(7 - (int)theDate.DayOfWeek);

Comment: saksham thanx man it worked.thanx a ton..u saved a lot of my time..just one more thing.i have put the date in a label in a table cell..how can i now extract it separatelt..suppose i want just the monday and thn its day that is 4 and the year 2013.so that i can use them in where clause

Comment: for "Sun" or "Mon" theDate.ToString("ddd");. For "Sunday" or "Monday" theDate.ToString("dddd"). for year, replace ddd with yyyy(lond form) or yy(short). For date dd

Comment: if found relevant, please give a thumbs up to the answer

Comment: use querystring to pass the date of the week which you want to show and when the page reloads, check the query string parameter and for that date load the calendar

Comment: hey man i have solved this.all thanks to you..you showed me the way..i did it by using session on every click..but now the thing is how do i use the cell text i mean i have to separate Monday, May 20, 2013 so that i can use them in my sql where clause?

Comment: string str=Monday, March 04, 2013  Can you tell me how to get Monday,04 and 2013 out of this string separately....i want to use them in my sql query like...select * from tblplan where day=04 march 2013....and in the second query i would like to use it as select * from tblcontent where day =monday date=04 and year =2013...how can i do this.can you suggest .and yes i m creating all of these dates in a table cell dynamically